# Can I run Untangle or other UTM before router?

Tags: networking, router

Since I read that Untangle does not work well with VLANs, I want to know if I can place the UTM before my router.

My ISP provides gigabit fiber. A box outside my house converts the fiber to ethernet. It then runs into my utility closet.

The server I want to run the UTM, is a SuperMicro 5018A-FTN4 (?) 8c 2.4GHz, 8GB DDR3 (can be upgraded to 32GB max). It has 4 Ethernet ports and 1 IPMI Ethernet port. My router is a Ubiquiti USG. I would like to keep it as it completes my Unifi Controller setup (gateway, switch, and WAP).

ISP -> Untangle (UTM) -> Router -> Switch -> End Devices

Comment: What are you running Untangled on, and what type of connection do you have to the ISP?  [edit] the question to add more info.

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  You can put whatever you prefer on the ethernet connection, and as the UTM can easily act as your border router, and it provides security, this is a good place for it.

Then you have the USG behaving like a core switch.  With incoming connections, you can NAT through the Untangle, then either route directly through the USG or do a double NAT if the USG is not flexible with how it works.  Either will work.

You will have three network address ranges effectively.  The public address provided by your ISP, a connecting network between the Untangle and USG, and then your internal VLANs. If you can route through the USG, then you'll need static routes on the Untangle routing your internal networks to the USG, otherwise, if you have to do double NAT, then no routing is needed.

Comment: I can create routes on the USG. Good to know I can do this before the router.